# Java generics syntax issue

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a method that gets 2 parameters:

1. an interface.
2. a class that implements that interface.

I want it to be generic (compile time type safe).

is there a way?
if not, whats the alternative?

is there an option to get generic param that is an interface? ho do I declare it? 
 ?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some thing like this ??

```
public <I, K extends I> void method(I i, K k){

    }
```

In the above method first parameter would be an interface, and second parameter would be any class that implements that interface.

```
    Interface1 i1;
    method(i1, class1); //class1 implements Interface1
```

In generics, interface implementation and class extending is represented using extends keyword. there is no implements keyword in the world of generics.

Comment: looks good.. just extends is for classes , can i use implemtes?

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T extends Interface> T myMethod(Interface I, Class<T> myClass) () {...}
```

if your method returns T